# Sql select query set html tags using for xml path

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am having two queries which retuns data containing html tag. Sql Query 1 works fine but Sql Query 2 not returns exact html tag,
query 2 data is nested html tag.

**Query 1 :**

```
declare @val1 nvarchar(max)
declare @val2 nvarchar(max)
set @val1='my value one';
set @val2='my value two';
select data=( select @val1 as td, '' ,@val2 as td for xml path('tr'))
```

**OutPut:**

```
<tr><td>my value one</td><td>my value two</td></tr>
```

---

**Query 2 :**

```
 select stuff(( select ','+'<span>'+@val1+'<span>'+@val2+'</span></span>'       
                  for xml path('')),1,1,'') as Col1
```

**Output:**

```
&lt;span&gt;my value one&lt;span&gt;my value two&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;
```

**Desired Output:**

```
<span>my value one<span>my value two</span></span>
```

Comment: Would `replace` not meet your requirements? Or perhaps, do the replacement in application code before rendering this HTML?

Comment: @shree.pat18: can you make query 2 using replace ?

Comment: You must use replace, or replace function , because stuff for xml path replaces special jason chars with &something. In your example its characters < and >... Just replace it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with nested `replace` like so:

```
select replace(replace(stuff(( select ','+'<span>'+@val1+'<span>'+@val2+'</span></span>'       
              for xml path('')),1,1,''), '&lt;','<'),'&gt;','>') as col1
```

Of course, you must keep in mind that for every escaped sequence of characters, you need to add one more level of nesting. Therefore, I suggest you do this in your application code which should have some sort of HTML encode-decode functionality in a standard library.

Comment: But better is create table with this special chars, and replace it dynamicaly. But its solution...

Comment: thank you currently  this solved my problem, and yes am thinking to change it later from my app code side

Comment: bad solution, replace chars is never a good way

Answer (score 0):

use correctly xml syntax:

```
declare @val1 nvarchar(max)
declare @val2 nvarchar(max)
set @val1='my value one';
set @val2='my value two';
select data=( select @val1 as td, '' ,@val2 as td for xml path('tr'))

select stuff(( select convert(xml,','+'<span>'+@val1+'<span>'+@val2+'</span></span>') for xml path('')),1,1,'') as Col1
```

before convert your string in xml

output : `<span>my value one<span>my value two</span></span>`

[example sql fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a6ab6949e3ab209468de9f6e3dd91343)